# type (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label) is not compatible with the type of control (ASP.controls_labelcontrol_ascx)

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

following problem is DotNetNuke related - but seems to me to be an asp.net related error and I do really appreciate every hint to solve this problem.

I have following problem: When editing the content of the Html module after a fresh install of DotNetNuke 7.4.2 in my dev environment (Win 8.1, , SqlServer 2008 R2 express, VS2013) the exception shown at the end raises. When installing 7.4.2 in the test environment (Win 2K8 server 64bit, SqlServer 2008 R2 express) editing the module is without an error and all works fine.

Installing was done using an empty database, modifying web.config to point to this database and calling http://dnndev.me/install/install.aspx. The web site has its own application pool and the application pool user has been granted the necessary rights to the installation folder(s). BTW: This procedure has been used successful (with modifications) beginning with DNN v4.

A google search did not show to much results. What I tried was to clear the "v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files" folder - no success.

Does anyone has an idea what the reason for this error can be?

Thanks for your ideas,
 Robert

```
Error: is currently unavailable. DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: 
The base class includes the field 'plCurrentWorkVersion', but its type (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label) 
is not compatible with the type of control (ASP.controls_labelcontrol_ascx). 
---> System.Web.HttpParseException: The base class includes the field 'plCurrentWorkVersion', 
but its type (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label) is not compatible with the type of control (ASP.controls_labelcontrol_ascx). 
---> System.Web.HttpParseException: The base class includes the field 'plCurrentWorkVersion', but its type (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label) 
is not compatible with the type of control (ASP.controls_labelcontrol_ascx). 
at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateCodeDomTreeGenerator.BuildFieldDeclaration(ControlBuilder builder) 
at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateCodeDomTreeGenerator.BuildSourceDataTreeFromBuilder(ControlBuilder builder, Boolean fInTemplate, Boolean topLevelControlInTemplate, PropertyEntry pse) 
at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateCodeDomTreeGenerator.BuildSourceDataTreeFromBuilder(ControlBuilder builder, Boolean fInTemplate, Boolean topLevelControlInTemplate, PropertyEntry pse) 
at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateCodeDomTreeGenerator.BuildSourceDataTreeFromBuilder(ControlBuilder builder, Boolean fInTemplate, Boolean topLevelControlInTemplate, PropertyEntry pse) 
at System.Web.Compilation.TemplateControlCodeDomTreeGenerator.BuildMiscClassMembers() 
at System.Web.Compilation.BaseCodeDomTreeGenerator.BuildSourceDataTree() 
at System.Web.Compilation.BaseCodeDomTreeGenerator.GetCodeDomTree(CodeDomProvider codeDomProvider, StringResourceBuilder stringResourceBuilder, VirtualPath virtualPath) 
at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.GenerateCode(AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder) 
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.AddBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) 
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.AddBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath virtualPath) 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResult(HttpContext context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) 
at System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath) 
at DotNetNuke.UI.ControlUtilities.LoadControl[T](TemplateControl containerControl, String ControlSrc) 
at DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleControlFactory.LoadModuleControl(TemplateControl containerControl, ModuleInfo moduleConfiguration) 
at DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleHost.LoadModuleControl() 
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

The related piece of markup code is

```
<asp:Label id="plCurrentWorkVersion" runat="server" text="Version" ResourceKey="plCurrentWorkVersion"  />
```

Comment: Seems like you've mixed up different DNN versions. Did you upgrade from a previous version in your dev machine? Did you remove the old one before installing the new one? There's a related discussion at http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/371687/scope/posts/events-module-not-working-properly-after-upgrade-of-dnn-amp-aspnet

Comment: Hi Panagiotis, the installation files are copied into an empty folder. Best Regards, Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've already deleted the site, then it is probably too late to check, but I would have checked if under the site there was an Application/VirtualDirectory on DesktopModules, or any of the sub folders in there. This is a common problem with my templates in Visual Studio, for some reason, randomly, VS will turn those folders into an individual application which causes all sorts of chaos until you remove the application in IIS.

Comment: This was the reason indeed (as I wrote in the edit section of the answer above). Deletion of the site did remove this folder and with this the usage of different versions during compilation disappeared. Thanks, Robert

Answer (score 0):

The site dnndev.me (and its application) had been used for other installations before.

Deleting and recreating the site (implying the application) **solved the error** (please note, that creating a new application pool was not enough).

If there is an explanation for this I would really appreciate this.

Edit: Comparing the current applicationHost.config with an older one showed the reason for the error: there was an additional entry  which pointed into a fully qualified name of a path in an other old version. This resulted in a compilation using two versions (and this is what Panagiotis already wrote).